# Tag wiki for CSV is about CVS

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

The [tag wiki](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tags/csv/info) for [csv](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csv) is about [CVS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System) instead [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

All questions tagged with [csv](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csv) seem to be about CSV.

I wasn’t sure if I should simply delete the wiki content (it’s rather detailed), or if there is a process to migrate it to a new tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can go ahead and write a new tag wiki for it. The old tag wiki will be preserved in the revision history in case we need to reference it again if a [cvs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cvs) tag pops up.

Since we don't have any questions that I can see that should be tagged with a [cvs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cvs) tag, there's no use in creating a tag for it now. It would just be culled when the tag-cleaner runs.